# I am encountering an issue while trying to connect my Express.js application to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-compass

Despite successfully making the connection, I am unable to create a database in MongoDB Compass.
Node v18.16.0
code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/largeData")
.then(()=>{
    console.log("connected successfull");
})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err);})
```

Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Have you confirmed the database is indeed running?
2. Is the code reaching the catch block and logging `err`? If so, please include the logs

Comment: yeah it is working there is configuration is unrestricted